# Volume swept by a polygon when it "slides" along a given curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Given a parametric curve $\mathbf{r}\left(s\right)$, where the parameter $s$ is the length of the curve, lets define a plane $\Pi$ perpendicular to the curve at a specific $s=s_1$. Lets also define a polygon $\mathcal{P} \in \Pi$ of $n$ given vertices (or more generally, a closed area $A \in \Pi$)

Now, lets "slide" the plane $\Pi$ along the curve to a new position $s=s_2$. My question is: How can I calculate the volume swept by the polygon $\mathcal{P}$ as function of $s_1$, $s_2$, and $\mathbf{r}\left(s\right)$?

Thanks in advance

(This question is related with the one that I posted yesterday: http://goo.gl/iH7YJu)

Comment: You may also need to specify how the plane $\Pi$ rotates (or what it means that it doesn't rotate) around the curve as it slides

Comment: Yep, let's say it does not rotate

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that $\mathbf{r}\left(s\right)$ is "sufficiently smooth" in $s\in[s_1, s_2]$ and its curvature $\kappa \left(s\right)$ is never zero in $s\in[s_1, s_2]$. If $\mathcal{V}$, the solid generated by the motion of the polygon $\mathcal{P}$ along the curve with the frame $\left\{\mathbf{n}(s),\mathbf{b}(s)\right\}$, is not self-intersecting, then the volume of $\mathcal{V}$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
V = AL + M_Y \int_{s_1}^{s_2} \kappa \left(s\right) \mathrm{d}s
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the area of the polygon $\mathcal{P}$, $L$ is the length of the curve between $s_1$ and $s_2$, and $M_Y$ is the moment of $\mathcal{P}$ about the initial binormal vector $\mathbf{b}(s_1)$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, In reference to the paper you sent me (http://www.jstor.org/stable/2316426), at pag.360 the properties of periodicity and smoothness of the curve C_P are used in order to simplify eq.21: seven equations are then obtained (eq.23-29). In my particular case, C_P is not smooth: it is actually a poligon, so it is not differenciable in the vertices. However, I think all these simplifications can be still done. Does the absence of smoothness affects to any of the simplifications done in eq.23-29?

Thanks you very much in advance

Comment: Since polygons are continuous and piecewise differentiable, there should be no issue - everything should still work if you interpret the derivatives as weak derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that sliding means that every point of a polygon has fixed coordinates in a Frenet frame. Let the original polygon (at $s=s_1$) has an area $A$. The volume can be computed as $A$ times the length of a curve from $s_1$ to $s_2$. Since $s$ is arclength parameter then it is $A(s_2-s_1)$.

Comment: This is not correct in general. It is only correct in linear translation and/or specific arrangements

Comment: this is the most general setup where it holds, unless I misunderstood what you think by "sliding".

Comment: You need a "balancing" condition on the polygon for this to be true - its centroid must lie in the binormal direction. See e.g. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2316426

Comment: It is by no means  a simple issue, one of the big ambiguities being self-intersections ! You should have a Google search with the keywords "tube" (this is the most usual name for a generalized cylinder) and "volume".

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree, here we assume a lot of simplifications for sure, no self intersections, everything is smooth etc.

Comment: @Anth I don't see the point where that condition should be used, Can you provide some details. I  will see the reference later

Comment: @user26977: think about the revolution of a disc about a circle to get a solid torus. If you offset the disc towards the centre of the circle, you create a smaller torus, but the cross-sectional area is not changed. For this case of a horizontal circle, the condition is that the centroid of the region/polygon should lie on the same vertical line as the curve.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I am studying the reference you sent me, and I have a question about it. If I am moving the vertices of the polygon as said in http://goo.gl/iH7YJu , Can I assume that the moving domain is rotating with the binormal vector? That would allow me to use the simpler equation (32) instead of the general one (eq. 44).

Comment: The OP said the polygon doesn't rotate, so you can't get a torus by sweeping a disc.

Comment: The polygon does not rotate within the plane $\Pi$ (i.e., if you look at the plane $\Pi$ as it moves, the polygon always is in the same position). But of course it spatially rotates: $\mathbf{r}\left(s\right)$ is a generic curve

Comment: @user3473823: You need to specify the manner in which you're transporting the vertices. Saying they "don't rotate within the plane" doesn't exactly make sense, since the normal planes at different points on the curve are different. The most natural way to transport is to rotate the polygon along with the frame {N,B}, which is the scheme that gives equation 32.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis -- my mistake. I misread the question, and the OP's comment led to further confusion.

Comment: Right, I am going to write the answer. Thank you very much!